# Abnormal behavior of web browser in OS X

Tags: macos, web-browser

I am using OS X  10.9.5

When every I click in any browser, it creates a new tab with some site like "www.detoxmymac.com".

It seems that the computer is full of processes running while I run any browser. Consumes huge power. How can I stop it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to running anti-virus software, as mentioned by Steve, above, you should check and clean out your browser's cache and extensions.

(1) Safari

> Safari --> Help --> Installed Plug-ins

Here, plug-ins called "Quicktime" and "Flash" are OK, and are not likely culprits.

> Safari --> Safari --> Preferences --> Extensions

Here, think long and hard about whether you actually need the services offered by any extension here.  If you do, check you've got the latest and disable or delete the rest.

> Safari --> Safari --> Preferences --> Advanced --> Proxies

Here, check to see if there are any proxies, which are instructions to visit some other site *before* going to the site you wish to visit.   Sometimes proxies are needed to get past restrictions put on you by your ISP, like the hotel you're staying at, but they're uniquely positioned to redirect you anywhere, and to pop open new web pages.

(2) Chrome

> Chrome --> Preferences... --> Extensions

Check here for any extension you don't recognize.  Disable or delete anything you don't need.

> Chrome --> Preferences... --> Settings -- > Search

Set your search engine to something you recognize and trust.  If you're in doubt, use "Google" or "DuckDuckGo" or even "Yahoo!" and delete the rest.

> Chrome --> Preferences... --> Settings -- > Show advanced settings... --> Network

Click here to look at your proxy settings.  Unless you need a proxy because you travel a lot, or you live in a repressive country, or your computer is part of an enterprise network, you probably don't need a proxy.

Comment: Yes it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is likely your Mac has been taken over by some malware, possibly from the website you mentioned.

Try booting into safe mode, reboot while holding the shift key, eventually the Mac startup screen will show safe mode. Booting into safe mode can take a lot longer than normal due to all the disk/file checks run at boot, so just let it work.

This turns off a lot of things (pretty much everything that doesn't come with the O/S, and some that do). Once you are booted to the desktop try Safari then.

The problem with spyware and Malware it is often difficult to remove and anti-virus Apps don't always get rid of the damn things. MacWorld UK had an interesting article on A/V for the Mac [here.](http://www.macworld.co.uk/feature/mac-software/mac-antivirus-internet-security-software-malware-review-3523842/)

Probably a good place to start. I would also Google that website and see if there is any malware specifically related to it with instructions to remove it.

I would be really tempted to manually back up any documents needed, boot the Mac into recovery mode and wipe the drive and start over from scratch. It might be a bit less nerve wracking...